# Should i use logger for this or code myself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, methods

I am using rails and many of you may find this simple, but i'm confused whether to use logger or just write method calls.

What i'm looking for is that when a user either deletes or updates data using the app, the changes made by the user must to saved to a table in the database with his user name, the record he modified and the time at which he did. 
Should i be using

> before_delete , before_update

callbacks in model.

I'm really hitting my head, cause i am a beginner in rails. Any suggestion would be most welcome and also please give a insight or links on what i should be doing.

Comment: Ideal answer: callbacks are really a bad idea. Short answer: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: @apneadiving would you explain why callbacks are bad idea?

Comment: i just want to log only when edited or deleted, user name i could fetch from sessions, time would be easy with rails built in methods. Thing is i don't want to complicate things(over kill) with using gems for simple job. Any idea on how to do this or is gem the only way. @apneadiving

Comment: callbacks do not know about context, they are executed every time. What they do is hidden by nature. Their side effects can be confusing and bug prone. Basically if you start having conditional callbacks, its highway to hell

Comment: Basically in this case, wrap update and delete actions with logging code. This can be in a service, easy to understand and to test. Otherwise you'd have to let the model know about the current user, which is none of its business

Comment: Thanks, will give that a try.